# Erlang flatten function time complexity

Tags: erlang, time-complexity, flatten

I need a help with following:

```
flatten ([]) -> [];

flatten([H|T]) -> H ++ flatten(T).
```

Input List contain other lists with a different length

For example:

```
flatten([[1,2,3],[4,7],[9,9,9,9,9,9]]).
```

What is the time complexity of this function?
And why?

I got it to O(n) where n is a number of elements in the Input list.

For example:

```
flatten([[1,2,3],[4,7],[9,9,9,9,9,9]])    n=3

flatten([[1,2,3],[4,7],[9,9,9,9,9,9],[3,2,4],[1,4,6]])    n=5
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'm not sure your code will work, at least not in the way standard library works.  You could compare your function with `lists:flatten/1` and maybe improve on your implementation. Try lists such as `[a, [b, c]]` and `[[a], [b, [c]], [d]]` as input and verify if you return what you expected.

Regarding complexity it is little tricky due to `++` operator and functional (immutable) nature of the language.  All lists in Erlang are linked lists (not arrays like in C++), and you can not just add something to end of one without modifying it; before it was pointing to end of list, now you would like it to link to something else.  And again, since it is not mutable language you have to make copy of whole list left of `++` operator, which increases complexity of this operator.

You could say that complexity of `A ++ B` is `length(A)`, and it makes complexity of your function little bit greater.  It would go something like `length(FirstElement) + (lenght(FirstElement) + length(SecondElement)) + ....` up to (without) last, which after some math magic could be simplified to `(n -1) * 1/2 * k * k` where `n` is number of elements, and `k` is average length of element. Or `O(n^3)`.

If you are new to this it might seem little bit odd, but with some practice you can get hang of it.  I would recommend going through few resources:

- Good [explanation](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists) of lists and how they are created
- Documentation on [list handling](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html) with **DO** and **DO NOT** parts
- Short [description](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#id61471) of `++` operator myths and best practices
- [Chapter](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion) about recursion and tail-recursion with examples using `++` operator